# Imagick Resize, Center, and Sparse Fill problems

Tags: php, resize, imagemagick, center, imagick

My end goal here is to resize the input image to 100px width, 125px height. Some of the input images are a different Aspect Ratio, so I wish for them to be in a 100x125 container with the background sparse filled from their edge color.

Ok, so this works for the basic resize:

```
$image = new Imagick($imgFile);
$image->resizeImage(100,0, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, false);
$image->writeImage("$Dir/$game.png");
header("Content-type: ".$image->getImageFormat());
echo $image;
$image->clear();
$image->destroy();
```

However I've been searching for hours, and I cannot find a simple "This is how you center an image in a canvas" bit for PHP's Imagick library. Everything is for the actual ImageMagick convert application, which is not really what I'm after. I've tried compositing the resized image into an empty newImage with the set width and height, but it just seems to overwrite the dimensions regardless of the composite type, setting the Gravity to center and then the extent to 100x125 has no effect ( It always sits at 0,0, and trying to set the y offset to ((125-imageheight)/2) resulted in an offset that was way more than it should have been )

Edit:

```
    $imageOutput = new Imagick();
    $image = new Imagick($imgFile);
    $image->resizeImage(100,0, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, false);
    $imageOutput->newImage(100, 125, new ImagickPixel('black'));
    $imageOutput->compositeImage($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_ADD, 0, ((125 - $image->getImageHeight()))/2 );
    $imageOutput->setImageFormat('png');
    $imageOutput->writeImage("$Dir/$game.png");
    header("Content-type: ".$imageOutput->getImageFormat());
    echo $imageOutput;
    $image->clear();
    $image->destroy();
```

So I got my centering working, gravity apparently has no effect on actual images.

I have absolutely no idea where I would even begin to try and recreate a command line edge-in sparse fill in PHP with the library.

Comment: Are you trying to take an image, say 500 * 500, and scale it down to fit into a 100 * 125 image? Then, because 500 * 500 doesn't perfectly scale, only make the height 125 and the width scale proportionally then center it vertically inside the box?

Comment: I'm trying to center a square vertically inside of a tall rectangle of the same width

Comment: Y = (rectangleHeight/2) - (squareHeight / 2)

Comment: I was already doing that and it wasn't working, turns out I was an idiot and completely forgot the () on the getImageHeight function, so my offset was half the size of the container instead...

Now I just need to figure out how to sparse fill the background based on the edge color instead of having a solid black background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of Imagick and shell calls to convert itself, I'll eventually rewrite it to use entirely shell calls. I also changed my dimensions, here's the code:

```
    $imageOutput = new Imagick(); // This will hold the resized image
    $image = new Imagick($imgFile); // Open image file
    $image->resizeImage(120,0, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, false); // Resize it width-wise
    $imageOutput->newImage(120, 150, "none"); // Make the container with transparency
    $imageOutput->compositeImage($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_ADD, 0, ((150 - $image->getImageHeight())/2) ); // Center the resized image inside of the container
    $imageOutput->setImageFormat('png'); // Set the format to maintain transparency
    $imageOutput->writeImage("$Dir/$game.temp.png"); // Write it to disk
    $image->clear(); //cleanup -v
    $image->destroy(); 
    $imageOutput->clear();
    $imageOutput->destroy();
    //Now the real fun
    $edge = shell_exec("convert $Dir/$game.temp.png -channel A -morphology EdgeIn Diamond $Dir/$game.temp.edge.png"); // Get the edges of the box, create an image from just that
    $shepards = shell_exec("convert $Dir/$game.temp.edge.png txt:- | sed '1d; / 0) /d; s/:.* /,/;'"); // get the pixel coordinates
    $final = shell_exec("convert $Dir/$game.temp.edge.png -alpha off -sparse-color shepards '$shepards' png:- | convert png:- $Dir/$game.temp.png -quality 90 -composite $Dir/$game.jpg"); // Sparse fill the entire container using the edge of the other image as shepards , then composite that on top of this new image
    unlink("$Dir/$game.temp.png"); // cleanup temp files
    unlink("$Dir/$game.temp.edge.png");
    set_header_and_serve("$Dir/$game.jpg"); // serve the newly created file
```

Comment: Then use just 1 line of shell:  
`exec( 'convert -resize ' . escapeshellarg( $w ) . 'x' . escapeshellarg( $h ) . ' -background escapeshellarg( $color ) -gravity center -extent ' . escapeshellarg( $w ) . 'x' . escapeshellarg( $h ) . ' ' . escapeshellarg( $input_png_path ) . ' ' . escapeshellarg( $output_png_path ) );`  
Resizes to $w x $h keeping proportions, 'extents' the canvas to the same given $w and $h (if needed), and fills the rest with any background $color ("white"). You get images always the same size with centered and proportional image (not deformed), rest filled with $color.

Comment: Without the escapeshellargs for better readability:  
`exec( "convert -resize $wx$h -background $color -gravity center -extent $wx$h $input_path $output_path" );`

Comment: That achieves a different goal than the one I was shooting for

Comment: You're right, I've mistaken "sparse" for "extent", but still you could fix my answer to your needs as it solves the "resize" and "center" part of your question. I didn't play much with sparse, but I'm pretty sure you could achieve what you want with less lines of code. I'll see if I can get an example working on my "sparse" time.

Comment: I do recall gravity not having any effect ( as noted in the initial question ), which was why I ended up doing it the way I did ( split between library and shell ); This project ended up dying though and I've never gone back to fix it up ( and mostly moved to other languages, fell out of love with PHP - That said, a full-shell variant would be accessible to other languages as well. )